# Why is there a big gap at the beginning of all the questions?

Tags: bug

Why is there a big gap at the beginning of all the questions? (see illustration below) Note that the gap is not present in meta. Is this a bug, or an intentional stylistic feature?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293336/215590

Comment: You're likely to get more knowledgeable answers on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for questions relating to functionality or issues with the Stack Exchange site itself (rather than GIS SE)

Comment: @Midavalo Only GIS has this gap.

Comment: @TylerDurden But your question is about functionality of Stack Exchange site, over which nobody at GIS SE (that I'm aware of) has any direct control over.

Comment: @TylerDurden Did the post that PolyGeo commented help at all?

Comment: Have you checked [so] for the gap?  I think GIS is one of relatively few sites that has ads enabled by SE.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, it is an ad issue (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

I did further research by examining the HTML source for the page. It turns out that the gap is supposed to be occupied by an ad. Since I have an ad blocker enabled, I just see blank space.

It is not clear why the gap only appears on GIS and not any other SE sites for me. It is possible that an old or incorrect ad format is being fed to GIS for some reason.

Comment: It's possible that you have more than 200 rep on other sites. IIRC, only users below 200 rep see an ad

Comment: Do you see an ad if you turn off your ad-blocker?

Comment: It does sound like the same issue that @PolyGeo posted a link for - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/tag-page-shows-lots-of-empty-space - take a look at the answers there.  It appears an explicit height was set, so the gap is there even if no ad is shown.  Sounds like the SE team are onto it and are (or have) fixed the problem.